# Why does pandas.Dataframe.drop() returns None?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here in my code I read the data from CSV:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('dataset/job_functions.csv', names=["job","category"] ,skiprows=1).dropna().reindex()
num_jobs = data["job"].size
```

Then I want to drop the rows which 'category' label does not equal to `i`:

```
data = data.drop(data[data.category!=i].index,inplace = True)
print(data.head())
```

Even dropping by the list of index returns None:

```
data = data.drop(data.index[[1,2,3]],inplace = True)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample.py", line 162, in 
  delete_common_words(27)
File "sample.py", line 92, in delete_common_words
  print(data.head())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Here is the data until I use the `drop()`:

```
                                                 job  category
0  офис   менеджер реализация гербицидовоформлени...         2
1  менеджер   отдел продажа работа с существующий...        27
2  ведущий   бухгалтер работа с вендер и поставщи...         1
3  менеджер   по продажа и продвижение продукт ус...        27
4  юрист   проведение юридический экспертиза прое...        13
```

Comment: But you passed `inplace=True` so it will return `None` this is correct behaviour, if you set `inplace=False` it would return the modified df

Comment: To add to the the above comment you will find that the appropriate rows have been doped from your frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','b', 'c']})
print (data)
  category
0        a
1        b
2        c

i = 'a'
print (data[data.category != i])
  category
1        b
2        c

print (data[~data.category.isin(['b','c'])])
  category
0        a
```

And as [`EdChum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827316/why-does-pandas-dataframe-drop-returns-none#comment65020368_38827316) explains, if use `inplace=True` it return `None`, so you can use:

```
#omit inplace=True
data = data.drop(data[data.category!=i].index)
```

Or:

```
#remove assigning
data.drop(data[data.category!=i].index,inplace = True)
```